# Cannot reduce ulimits inside docker container

Tags: docker, ulimit

I want to use `ulimit -f` inside a docker container to *reduce* the limits. (I stress this as many questions and answers around this involve *increasing* limits).

I have a script that writes a 10k file, and reports successs:

```
$ perl examples/largefile.pl
Begin
End
```

I can prevent it from running to completion, as expected, with `ulimit -f`:

```
$ ( ulimit -f 5 ; perl examples/largefile.pl )
Begin
```

Unfortunately, inside a cocker container, the `ulimit -f` command doesn’t seem to haven an effect:

```
$ sudo docker run --rm -i -t -u 1001 -v $PWD:$PWD safe-docker bash
user@08aba80ebaff:/$ cd ...
user@08aba80ebaff:/...$ examples/largefile.pl
Begin
End
user@08aba80ebaff:/...$ ( ulimit -f 5 ; perl examples/largefile.pl )
Begin
End
```

but note how `ulimit` *believes* it had an effect:

```
user@08aba80ebaff:/...$ ( ulimit -f; ulimit -f 5; ulimit -f)
unlimited
5
```

Passing `--privileged` to `docker run` does not help.

This is related to my [earlier question](http://expertsoverflow.com/questions/25744278), but there I wonder about *inheriting* limits from the caller to `docker run`, whereas here I wonder about setting limits inside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this was recently implemented in docker: https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4717